# Lock the SWF stage size

Tags: actionscript-2

how do i lock the stage size of the SWF file, so that no matter how the user stretches the player, it wont expose what is outside the stage (e.g. enemy spawn points, the stage's background, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

thats dependent on the size you specify in your html embed. give it fixed sizes instead of percentages on the embed, or better yet use swfobject to embed your swf

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=wrapper_13.html

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

or you could just mask your stage area so that anything revealed outside is masked out.

Comment: oh, i think i forgot to tell that it is in a standalone flash swf player. I tried the fscommand but I can still see the outer areas of the stage when I stretch the swf player...:)